# VB.net (Peer to Peer Connection Issue)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, tcp, p2p

Given the VB.net code in the image (I apologize it's an image and not text), please help solve an issue. The problem is that when I want to send a string to another device, the string is not delivered until I close the program that is running. The string should be delivered without having to close the program.

[Here is the Code in the Visual Studio environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lMp8.png)

Note that the code is mostly from the following website: *http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/21431-p2p-connections/*

A few changes were made from the reference code from that website. For example, I hard-coded the string that is going to be sent. I also allow the user to input the IP address in a textbox once the program is running. These changes shouldn't affect my problem though.

If you would like the context of this code, I am sending commands to electronic devices (i.e. Agilent Signal Analyzers & Generators). The problem is that the command is not sent (or received) until I close the running program. Interestingly, if I enter the local host IP address 127.0.0.1 instead of the IP addresses of the agilent devices, I receive the string *without* having to close my program. It could be an issue with the Agilent devices, but I am not sure about that because my colleague was able to interact with the devices using C/C++ code. It is interesting to note that when I comment out the code for the timer, I cannot send anything to myself (local host), but the functionality is still the same when I send the command to the other device (it accepts it after I close the program). That is how far I have narrowed down the issue.

Comment: No VB there, only "VB.Net" The Great Pretender.

Comment: I corrected it to say VB.net. Thank you for that little tip. I have minimal experience with VB or VB.net

Comment: @Bob77, VB.NET has been just VB since 2005. You people need to get over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. On the agilent devices, I was using socket port 5025. It worked for my colleague and I assumed it would work for me. I decided to change the settings of the agilent device to enable the telnet port 5023 and I changed my code accordingly. Now it works!